# Cocoa [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:filePath caused memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsimage, nsworkspace

I am creating a cocoa application where i need to find out the icon images of file/directory. I am using this for getting icon image form the given path.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path];
```

This method is called recessively in whole application. The allocated memory of the application is increased as much i use my app. Using instruments when i look for the memory leaks, i find out that the above method is responsible for the 100% memory leaks.
How can i remove this memory leaks, or is their any other way why which i can get icon image and memory will not be a problem.
Please help me someone.
Thanks

Edited:

This is the method from which i am calling this method.

```
-(WEFile *)fileAtPath:(NSString *)filePath
{

    WEFile *file                = [[WEFile alloc] init];
    file.fIconImage             = [workSpace iconForFile:filePath];

    file.Name                   = [fileManager displayNameAtPath:filePath];
    file.type                   = [workSpace localizedDescriptionForType:[workSpace typeOfFile:filePath error:&error]];

    NSDictionary *detailDict    = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    file.modificationDate       = [ Utility createDateFormat:[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate]];
    file.creationDate           = [ Utility createDateFormat:[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]];
    file.Size                   = [[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileSize] integerValue];
    file.fPath                  = filePath;

    NSDictionary *metaDict      = [self metadataForFileAtPath:filePath];
    file.addedDate              = [ Utility createDateFormat:[metaDict objectForKey:@"kMDItemDateAdded"]];
    file.lastOpenedDate         = [ Utility createDateFormat:[metaDict objectForKey:@"kMDItemLastUsedDate"]];  
    return [file autorelease];

}
```

The method fileAtPath is called recursively from another and the WEFile class objects are stored  in a array. and display in a tableview.

EDIT 2: Here is the code from where i call fileAtPath method. And this method  directoryAtPath is called when table selection passing path of directory as a parameter.

```
-(WEDirectory *)directoryAtPath:(NSString *)dirPath
{

    WEDirectory *dir      = [[[WEDirectory alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSArray *childArray = [self getContentsWithinDirectory:dirPath];

    if (childArray && [childArray count]>0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i<[childArray count]; i++)
      {

         NSURL *fileURL     = [childArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *filePath = [self getPathFromURL:fileURL];
         filePath    = [filePath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         BOOL isDir;

         BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:&isDir];
         if (!success)
         {
               continue;
         }

        if(isDir)
        {

           WEDirectory *childDir       = [[WEDirectory alloc] init] ;
           childDir.dIconImage         = [workSpace iconForFile:filePath];

           childDir.Name               = [fileManager displayNameAtPath:filePath];
           childDir.type               = [workSpace localizedDescriptionForType:[workSpace typeOfFile:dirPath error:&error]];


           NSDictionary *detailDict    = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
           childDir.modificationDate   = [ Utility createDateFormat:[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate]];
           childDir.creationDate       = [ Utility createDateFormat:[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]];
           childDir.Size               = [[detailDict objectForKey:NSFileSize]integerValue];
           childDir.dPath              = filePath;

           [dir.childsArray addObject:childDir];
           [childDir release];
        }
        else 
        {
            WEFile *childFile = [self fileAtPath:filePath];
            [dir.childsArray addObject:childFile];

        }
      }
    }

    return dir ;

}
```

Comment: It depends what you are doing with the `NSImage` object (the way you get it is not relevant).

Comment: Please have a look to edited one.

Comment: Have you checked how `WEFile` manages its memory?  (i.e. does it call `self.fIconImage = nil;` is its `dealloc` method)?

Comment: (I editted my previous comment after realizing you couldn't be using ARC).  Anyway the issue is in the `WEFile` class.

Comment: In WEFile, i have implemented self.fIconImage = nil;     Also i tried with ARC but still app allocations are increasing continuously.

Comment: Could you show the code that is calling fileAtPath: ?

Comment: Hi Zorg. I have editing my question. please check EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

This works without causing memory leaks in my code - checked it with Leaks/Allocations:

`GAppSettings.h` your WEFile-class

```
NSImage *gAppIcon;
@property (readwrite, retain)   NSImage  *gAppIcon;
```

*.m
@synthesize gAppIcon;

in ->`init`

```
gAppIcon = nil;
```

in -> `dealloc`

```
[ gAppIcon release];
```

I am also using for storing and restoring
->`initWithCoder`

```
self.gAppIcon = [ decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"gAppIcon"];
```

->`encodeWithCoder`

```
[ coder encodeObject:   [ self gAppIcon] forKey:    @"gAppIcon"];
```

and

```
- ( id ) copyWithZone:  ( NSZone  *)zone
{
    return self;
}
```

The icon is loaded frequently in another class:

```
GAppSettings *appSettings = [ [ [GAppSettings alloc] init] autorelease];

...
NSImage *appIcon = [ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:completeAppPath];
[ appSettings setGAppIcon:appIcon];
...
return appSettings;
```

Then added to an array...